# How to serve Laravel 8 project on Apache2 by IP address?

Tags: laravel, ip, apache2

I am currently facing this issues. My Laravel project does not have a domain name, and probably will be issued later. By now I'd like to make it available by ip address. The "/" works just fine, but all the other routes do not work. My virtualhost.conf file is structured like this:

```
Alias /api /var/www/api/public
<VirtualHost *:80>
        <Directory /var/www/api/public>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                RewriteEngine On
                AllowOverride All
                Order Deny,Allow
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: there is probably something wrong with your .htaccess https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/why-do-my-laravel-routes-not-work https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-5-only-home-page-route-working-on-live-server These helped me when I had issues.

Comment: @bgeertsema2000 I was using the default .htaccess from Laravel. I couldn't resolve this issue, but I had an old unused project with a domain and I made the domain point to this Laravel project. It worked just fine.